# Detecting simultaneous RMB and LMB presses on Raspberry Pi and Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp, raspberry-pi3

Hello I am trying to detect if both the Left and Right buttons are being pressed at the same time in UWP.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, there is no direct event indicated that LMB and RMB are both pressed. [PointerUpdateKind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.pointerupdatekind) specifies the types of pointer updates that are supported by an application.

You can detect only in an indirect method. Notice that, when pressing right mouse button meanwhile left mouse button is being pressed, it will invoke the **PointerMoved** event instead of PointerPressed.

```
private bool leftButtonPressed = false;
private bool rightButtonPressed = false;   

//Scenario1OutputRoot is the ui element.
void Scenario1OutputRoot_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(Scenario1OutputRoot);
    if (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind != Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.Other)
    {
        this.buttonPress.Text += (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

        if (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.LeftButtonPressed)
        {
            leftButtonPressed = false;
        }

        if (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.RightButtonPressed)
        {
            rightButtonPressed = false;
        }
    }              
 }

void Scenario1OutputRoot_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(Scenario1OutputRoot);
    if (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind != Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.Other)
    {
        this.buttonPress.Text += (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

        if (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.LeftButtonPressed)
        {
            leftButtonPressed = true;
        }

        if (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.RightButtonPressed)
        {
            rightButtonPressed = true;
        }
   }            

   if (leftButtonPressed && rightButtonPressed)
   {
       this.buttonPress.Text = "both the Left and Right buttons are being pressed ";
   }
}

void Scenario1OutputRoot_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint pt = e.GetCurrentPoint(Scenario1OutputRoot);
    if(pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind != Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.Other)
    {
        this.buttonPress.Text += (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);

        if (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.LeftButtonPressed)
        {
            leftButtonPressed = true;
        }

        if (pt.Properties.PointerUpdateKind == Windows.UI.Input.PointerUpdateKind.RightButtonPressed)
        {
            rightButtonPressed = true;
        }

        if (leftButtonPressed && rightButtonPressed)
        {
            this.buttonPress.Text = "both the Left and Right buttons are being pressed ";
       }
   }    

   e.Handled = true;
}
```